# What url will be used when using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Let say I have a website called mywebiste.com. Inside my website I call an iframe with url called myiframe.com in which has a function that calls an api. So what is the client Url that will be hitting the api? Is it mywebsite.com or myiframe.com?

Comment: myiframe.com as it's that website which is calling the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myiframe.com` will call the api and `mywebsite.com` will not know that it happened. iframes are like a blackbox.